# Can I uninstall built in apps?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Can I uninstall default applications that come with the Android OS?

For eg:contacts,calendar,message.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How can you uninstall an app that you didn't install on your Droid?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-can-you-uninstall-an-app-that-you-didnt-install-on-your-droid), [How can I uninstall apps that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor), [Rooted phone but still can't uninstall apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/rooted-phone-but-still-cant-uninstall-apps)

Comment: Also, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/how-to-uninstall-htc-applications-widgets, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/uninstall-sprint-apps-without-rooting, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-remove-pre-installed-apps-like-peep-and-friend-stream-from-my-htc-phone