# How to remove Samsung native email app from Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, uninstallation, samsung-email

I only use the Gmail app. It's annoying to have the email icon always popping aside from the Gmail icon in every contact of my phone when I only use Gmail.

Is there a way to uninstall or wipe the Samsung email app/client from Galaxy S2? I just can't find a way to take it off my phone.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: [How can I uninstall built in apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/can-i-uninstall-built-in-apps), [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor) Probably a few others.

Comment: Note that the Email app might be a *required* system app, and removing it could make the OS unstable.  I don't see how a tiny icon you don't have to even look at is annoying, personally.

Comment: No, you can remove Email. It might break other Google applications, but the phone still works.