# Is Uninstalling built in apps safe?

Tags: applications

I have a rooted Lolipop 5.1 phone and I was wondering if uninstalling built in apps safe like Lookout, Hangout or Google+.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/can-i-uninstall-built-in-apps?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can manually delete them from the `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app` directory, or maybe using an system remover app.
Also, not all apps can be removed safely, for example, there are some core phone apps like `framework-res`, `SystemUI`. **Do not delete them!** If you're unsure, I suggest you to get information about it first.

Comment: The OP mentioned in the question that his phone is rooted.

Comment: Whoops, ok edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use a app like **[System app remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en)** for that.
And most of the apps are safe to remove, as the mentioned app shows if the app to be removed is a core component.

Comment: Please add a link to the mentioned app. Also, most apps are not safe to remove - very few system apps are safe to remove. However, in case of the OP, the apps he/she is considering for removal is safe to remove.

Comment: My bad, I tought adding links was illegal.

Comment: It's not illegal - it's recommended as per site policy (even when you are involved with the app, like being its developer - then you have to disclose your involvement).