# Can I remove all these garbage apps without rooting the phone?

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, uninstallation

I just got a Samsung Galaxy 2 from Docomo in Japan.

The only thing I don't like about it is that it came with about a million pre-installed apps, 99% of which are just garbage that clutter my application list. I'm not just talking about a few that I don't like, I'm talking about so many that I have to scroll through pages to get at the apps I want.

I was unable to uninstall a handful by going to the Market and simply opting to uninstall.

However, with all the rest, the uninstall button is greyed out.

Can I remove these apps without rooting the phone, and if so how?

If I have to root the phone, is that possible with my model?

Comment: Also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/can-i-uninstall-built-in-apps, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-can-you-uninstall-an-app-that-you-didnt-install-on-your-droid, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/uninstall-sprint-apps-without-rooting